# ISP IP address confusion

Tags: networking, router, ip, static-ip

I am using static IP provided by my ISP.

Recently I required to setup a host for video call conference by Polycom RealPresence Desktop, which required Static IP.

I had 1 ip already  `***.***.88.205`. Then I asked my ISP to provide me an additional IP.

Now they emailed me that please use the below LAN subnet `***.***.88.224/30`, now I am confused how to use this IP.

Comment: Did they give you a gateway to use with your subnet, or any other information in that email? We can make a best guess, but it's best if we don't accidentally conflict with their setup

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr ask your ISP prior to making changes and consult the camera vendor since you may have an XY problem**

**If you have a security or risk management department, consult with them too. There are real security implications to each of the possible configurations.**

The subnet xx.xx.88.224/30 has the following characteristics:

88.224 is the "network ID" and 88.237 is the "broadcast ID"
The "usable IPs" 88.225 and 88.226 are left over, but the question remains of who is meant to use them, you or your ISP?

There are a few possibilities:

1. They want you to use 88.225 and 88.226 by putting them on your router's DMZ or otherwise introducing an internal route to the 88.224/30 subnet.

   In turn the ISP will be routing external traffic to your router based on some other address.

   The ISP I work with would use your old static IP of 88.205 for this purpose, meaning you would not need to change your router's WAN configuration.

   I suspect that they could also begin to assign DHCP to your router, and bind your subnet to that IP, but that's enough of a headache that it's unlikely.
2. Ask them before trying this configuration--**they will NOT be happy if you cause a broadcast storm!**

   Your ISP presumably provides one physical connector. They may mean to have you bridge the device that's plugged into that connector, or install a switch, and continue to use 88.205 with your current gateway and netmask on one device and additionally program the second device or router to use the following information:

   ```
   IP: xx.xx. 88.226
   Gateway: xx.xx.88.225
   Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.252
   ```
3. This configuration is incredibly obnoxious to implement.

   Your ISP may expect you to use both usable IPs similar to option 1, but without a third IP on your router's WAN. To make this work, they would provide a gateway that's outside of your subnet like [some hosting providers.](https://serverfault.com/q/595126)

**You also need more clarity from your video conferencing vendor.**

Often, needing "a static IP" is not the same as needing "a unique public static IP for just this device." Odds are, you can achieve the objective without needing to pay for two public IPv4 addresses.

Consider the following diagram:

ISP > your router using 88.205 publicly > the device that caused you to rent the first static IP AND other devices that don't care what kind of public address they get.

If that diagram sounds familiar **you can probably use whatever method your first device is working with to configure the video system so that they're both behind the existing public static.**

How:

By default your router is probably NATing the internal subnet 192.168.0.0/24. Your router listens on .1 as the gateway.

DHCP scope beginning .2 ending .254 (not .255 because .255 is the broadcast address)

Whatever device/service currently requires you to have a static is probably either given a "DHCP reservation" in the router to assure that it always gets the same internal address, or you have been real lucky.

Rather than reservations, you could change the DHCP scope to .4-.254 and program your existing device to use .2 statically and use .3 statically on the new video system.

Even better, pull from the high end of the subnet so that if your router gets factory reset it doesn't immediately vend a conflicting IP. *

---

[*] yes it's supposed to arp first but I've seen that fail too often to trust